# Merging two tensorflow Datasets, albeit at a different pace

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am looking for a way to merge a `Dataset` with another, but by drawing samples from it only occasionally.

For example, given these two `Dataset`s

```py
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10).repeat()
ds10 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10, 100, 10).repeat()
```

I would like to add samples from `ds10` to those of `ds1` but only for every two samples, so that the result would be

```py
ds = my_merge(ds1, ds10)
list(ds)
# 11, 2, 23, 4, 35, 6, 47...
```

Is this possible? I would like to avoid solutions discarding samples from `ds10` as this would be inefficient in my case.

EDIT The resulting `ds` needs to be a `Dataset` so that further input pipeline operations (e.g. batching) can be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `ds10` dataset based on skip parameter

```
skip = 2

pattern = np.concatenate(([0], np.ones((skip-1)))).astype(np.int64)
choice_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((pattern)).repeat()

zeros = tf.data.Dataset.range(0,1).repeat()
ds10 = tf.data.Dataset.choose_from_datasets([ds10, zeros], choice_dataset)

#[10, 0, 20, 0, 30, 0, 40, 0, 50]
```

Zip and add both dataset values

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1,ds10))
ds = ds.map(lambda x,y:x+y)

#[11, 2, 23, 4, 35, 6, 47, 8, 59]
```

Checking the performance,

```
def time_ds():
  for element in ds.take(1000):
    pass
def time_ds1():
  for element in ds1.take(1000):
    pass
%timeit time_ds() 29.3 ms ± 133 µs 
%timeit time_ds1() 23.5 ms ± 94.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: Interesting -- so there is not direct solution to draw occasionally from one `Dataset`, one needs to fill the blanks with fake values instead.

Comment: You can check `tf.data.Dataset.choose_from_datasets`, the `choice_dataset` param, can be configured such that you can choose how to sample across datasets. But your problem involved 'adding values' between dataset. So this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: @user209974 i hope you realise my solution is the direct solution to draw occasionally from one dataset, but as i said it is less efficient, but it has arbitrary complexity, but if you know what you are doing i'd choose this answer over mine.

Comment: This solution is really slow on my side, to the point that is is actually unusable.

Comment: I have edited to show that there is hardly any loss in performance when loading the concatenated ds compared to just loading  ds1. Your issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own generator:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import partial

ds1_unrepeated = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10)  # because repeat prevents element_spec
ds1_spec = ds1_unrepeated.element_spec
ds1 = ds1_unrepeated.repeat()
ds10 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10, 100, 10).repeat()

def my_merge(iter1,iter2):
    sliced_iter2 = iter(iter2)
    sliced_iter1 = iter(iter1)
    while True:
        yield next(sliced_iter1)+next(sliced_iter2)
        yield next(sliced_iter1)


ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(partial(my_merge,ds1,ds10),output_signature=ds1_spec)
for element in ds:
    print(element)
```

```
tf.Tensor(11, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(23, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(35, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(47, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

Edit: I have updated it to be a dataset, but I think the answer at the top is more efficient, this answer is only if the answer should be as lazily evaluated as possible, with little knowledge about the inputs, ie: the merging can be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: The solution is elegant but it has a flaw: the result is not a `Dataset`, which means that I cannot further add operations like batching, prefetching, aso. (I edited my question accordingly)

Comment: @user209974 i have edited it to be a dataset, but i think the answer at the top will be more efficient, my answer is only as lazy as possible with little knowledge about the inputs.